# Incrementing the array pointer beyond the last item

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I was having a little fun with C Programming and array pointers.

Can someone explain what is happening when I advance an array pointer beyond the size of the array?

It looks like I'm accessing the memory cell that is directly after the array, but I just want to be sure.

1. Do these numbers mean anything?
2. Why is the last number a zero?
3. Should a program be able to access memory it hasn't allocated?

So many questions!

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int *xPtr = arr;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("current pointer is %d\n", *xPtr++);
}
```

Results in:

```
current pointer is 1
current pointer is 2
current pointer is 3
current pointer is 4
current pointer is 5
current pointer is 0
current pointer is 127926431
current pointer is -759946469
current pointer is -492049712
current pointer is 32766
```

This was the only way I found to properly iterate through the array.  Is this correct?

```
int arraySize = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    printf("current pointer is %d\n", *xPtr++);
}
```

Results in:

```
current pointer is 1
current pointer is 2
current pointer is 3
current pointer is 4
current pointer is 5
```

Comment: "*`sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int)`*" Although correct, the preferred way to determine the number of elements of an array is `sizeof arr/sizeof *arr`. Please note that `sizeof` is an operator, and not a function.

Comment: Welcome to the world of [undefined behaviour](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), have fun.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are accessing memory outside the array. Array has just 5 elements, and you increase the pointer beyond that, and dereference it. There are actually two kinds of bad things here: you are dereferencing outside the array, but you are also increasing the pointer more than one step beyond end of the array. Neither is allowed.

This is undefined behaviour, so anything could happen. In this case it looks like you are simply getting the memory contents after the array, interpreted as ints. In the context of your C program, they're just garbage values, because once you have undefined behaviour in C, all bets are off, the program could have crashed or worse.

If you want to make sense of a program which has UB, you gotta compile it, then look at the assembly code of that particular compilation. Just note that next time you compile it, result could be different (compiler switches, compiler or library updates, different computer...), and the new assembly code could have totally different behaviour (because the C code had UB). Generally this is not useful, UB is UB and it rarely makes sense to try and reason about what it does.

---

C has no array bounds checking, so C compiler does not perform any checks. In a modern PC operating system with memory protection, 
the OS will kill the program if you try to access memory that is not given to it, but it has coarse resolution (for example 4 KB pages), and there might be a lot of memory belonging to your program anyway, so OS might not notice anything bad for megabytes after the array.

---

2nd version looks good. Just remember that `sizeof` works like that only for actual arrays, not for pointers, and not for array parameters of functions (because those are actually pointers, not arrays, despite the syntax).

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand pointer increment `*xPtr++` works by incrementing the size of the object it is pointing to. In your case being an `int`, every operation does an increment of the `sizeof(int)` depending on the size of `int` in your system.

Since your array has only 5 elements, on a machine with a 4 byte `int`, you cannot increment it more than 5 counts. Beyond that you are accessing memory that is not allocated for the array and accessing the value from those locations invokes undefined behavior.

Your second approach seems right, with a simple fix use the return type of `sizeof()` from `int` to `size_t` although an implicit conversion happens on assignment

```
size_t arraySize = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
for(size_t i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    printf("current pointer %p and value is %d\n", (void*)xPtr, *xPtr++);
}
```

Comment: Nitpick on the wording: "*... change the return type of `sizeof()` from `int` to `size_t`*" `The `sizeof` operator *always* evaluates to `size_t`. The OP just only assigned its result to an `int`, which lead to an "*implicit conversion*" from `size_t` to `int`. This you changed.

Comment: Nitpick^2 : Please note that the `p` conversion specifier is to be use with `void`-pointers only. So a pointer to be printed ought to be casted to `void*`.

Answer (score 3):

C does not check for Array Bounds. So even if you access an array beyond it's size which is declared, it will not give any error. The answers to your questions, according to me :

1. No the numbers are purely garbage value.
2. The last number can be anything (garbage including zero). As per ISO C standard it is called Undefined Behavior.
3. No it shouldn't! But C is a language of the time when compilers were slow and even saving 3-4 instructions in Assembly meant a lot!

Comment: #3 wasn't because of slow compilers and performance. The ability to access memory beyond array bounds was necessary in the 1970s and it's still necessary today.

Comment: Could you tell me why is it necessary?

Comment: Too many reasons to list, but the main one would be it's not always known what the array size is in advance. Sometimes that's only known at run-time and C doesn't have an elegant way of dealing with that.

Comment: @CareyGregory: "*The ability to access memory beyond array bounds was necessary in the 1970s and[...] is still necessary today.*" Not meant offending, but I feel placing such a statement without detailed reasoning is not just confusing, but also makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 3):

When you increment the pointer beyond the size of the array, yes, you're accessing the memory just after the array. It will contain just any random value called **garbage** value.

These garbage values are of no use in your program and you should avoid accessing it using the below for loop as mentioned in your answer:

```
int arraySize = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{ 
      printf("current pointer is %d\n", *xPtr++); 
}
```

These values don't mean anything. They're just values which were already stored in that particular memory location before you accessed it.

Let me walk you through an example.
Consider a 2D array and a pointer pointing to it

```
int a[2][2];
int *p = &a[0][0];
```

Now, take a careful look at indices.
If you try `p+0` it will point to `a[0][0]`, `p+1` will point to `a[0][1]`.
But if you try `p+2` now it will point to `a[1][0]` as this is just the next memory location.

And beyond `p+3` i.e. from `p+4` all values will be garbage.

Answer (score 3):

It depends where one declares array (more precisely storage location of the array).  If you declared any type of array without initialization as global or static then by default it is initialized to zero; otherwise if you declare it inside any function ie auto without initialization, then it will contain garbage value. Here in your program, when accessing a location in memory out of array bounds, then the value the program gets is a garbage value. Because by default each memory location contains garbage value. On initializing an array a block of memory get assigned with values you provided. Second thing is there is no best of iterating array; it totally depends on you.

On incrementing a pointer, it is incremented by the size of the object it is pointing, pointing to next element in array. Like for example:

```
data_type  arr[10];
```

Increment of pointer will take place by sizeof(data_type).
In C accessing unallocated memory may throw exceptions/warning.